# Wildcard file paths with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have time series data generated in blob store organized with folders like 2020/10/05/23/file1.json
Can a single copy activity in Azure Data Factory Copy be configured to process all such files and push it to data warehouse ? It is not clear to me, how can I configure to detect unprocessed folders?

Any pointers shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a copy activity with wildcards:
[image: Wildcard source]

Comment: On a periodic basis, how will it ignore already processed files

Comment: @DanglingPointer If you are running this on a daily or monthly basis you can set the wildcard directory to the day or month you want. If there is no patern then keep track of the last time you retrieved data and stick that value in the "Filter by last modified" Start time (UTC) field.